# Unhandled exception at 0x77f8f397 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00030ff0 &&& CXX0013: Error: missing operator

Tags: visual-c++

I wrote a program in visual C++ to display position and velocity. It worked fine. When I extended the code to display error. Eventhough I just added from visual studio. I get the access violation error, The error in code occurs first at "CEdit" from testDLg.h. Class CEdit is produced by default in axfwin.h by visual studio in windows.

```
// testDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "test.h"
#include "testDlg.h"
//#include <timer.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

#pragma comment(lib,"Mx4nt.lib")
extern "C"
{
#include "mx4nt.h"
#include "mx4dll.h"

int pstn = 0;

// The following function is not included in the DLL's header file, but
// it is included in the DLL.
NOMANGLE BYTE _stdcall r_1byte( int offset );
NOMANGLE BYTE _stdcall w_1byte( int offset, unsigned char data );
}



// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

protected:
virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialog(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CtestDlg dialog



CtestDlg::CtestDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CtestDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CtestDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT10, tab1);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT11, tab2);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT12, tab3);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT13, tab4);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT14, tab5);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT15, tab6);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT16, tab7);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, pos1);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT3, pos2);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT5, pos3);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT7, pos4);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT2, vel1);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT4, vel2);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT6, vel3);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT8, vel4);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT9, ferr1);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT17, ferr2);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT18, ferr3);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT19, ferr4);

}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CtestDlg, CDialog)
ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP

ON_WM_TIMER()

END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CtestDlg message handlers

BOOL CtestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
CDialog::OnInitDialog();

// Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

// IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
if (pSysMenu != NULL)
{
CString strAboutMenu;
strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
{
pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
}
}

// Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
//  when the application's main window is not a dialog
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE); // Set big icon
SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE); // Set small icon

clear_dspl();
reset_MX4();
SetTimer(1,50,NULL);

// TODO: Add extra initialization here

GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT10)->SetWindowText("axis1");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT11)->SetWindowText("axis2");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT12)->SetWindowText("axis3");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT13)->SetWindowText("axis4");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT14)->SetWindowText("position");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT15)->SetWindowText("velocity");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT16)->SetWindowText("error");

GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT3)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT4)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT5)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT6)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT7)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT8)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT9)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT17)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT18)->SetWindowText("");
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT19)->SetWindowText("");

pos_preset(1, pstn);

return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CtestDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
{
CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
dlgAbout.DoModal();
}
else
{
CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
}
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CtestDlg::OnPaint()
{
if (IsIconic())
{
CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

// Center icon in client rectangle
int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
CRect rect;
GetClientRect(&rect);
int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

// Draw the icon
dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
}
else
{
CDialog::OnPaint();
}

/*
CString str[8];
str[0].Format("%f",pos(1));
str[1].Format("%f",pos(2));
str[2].Format("%f",pos(3));
str[3].Format("%f",pos(4));
str[4].Format("%f",vel(1));
str[5].Format("%f",vel(2));
str[6].Format("%f",vel(3));
str[7].Format("%f",vel(4));
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(str[0]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT3)->SetWindowText(str[1]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT5)->SetWindowText(str[2]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT7)->SetWindowText(str[3]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2)->SetWindowText(str[4]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT4)->SetWindowText(str[5]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT6)->SetWindowText(str[6]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT8)->SetWindowText(str[7]);
*/
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CtestDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

void CtestDlg::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

//pstn += 100;
//pos_preset(1, pstn);
maxacc(1, 1.0);
velmode(1, 1.0);

CString str[8];
str[0].Format("%f",pos(1));
str[1].Format("%f",pos(2));
str[2].Format("%f",pos(3));
str[3].Format("%f",pos(4));
str[4].Format("%f",vel(1));
str[5].Format("%f",vel(2));
str[6].Format("%f",vel(3));
str[7].Format("%f",vel(4));
str[8].Format("%f",ferr(1));
str[9].Format("%f",ferr(2));
str[10].Format("%f",ferr(3));
str[11].Format("%f",ferr(4));
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(str[0]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT3)->SetWindowText(str[1]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT5)->SetWindowText(str[2]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT7)->SetWindowText(str[3]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2)->SetWindowText(str[4]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT4)->SetWindowText(str[5]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT6)->SetWindowText(str[6]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT8)->SetWindowText(str[7]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT9)->SetWindowText(str[8]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT17)->SetWindowText(str[9]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT18)->SetWindowText(str[10]);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT19)->SetWindowText(str[11]);

//KillTimer(1);
//i = i+100;

//Invalidate();

CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}

-- 
- Nandhini
www.linkedin.com/in/nandhinisudarsanan

// testDlg.h : header file
//

#pragma once
#include "afxwin.h"


// CtestDlg dialog
class CtestDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
CtestDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL); // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
enum { IDD = IDD_TEST_DIALOG };

protected:
virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX); // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
HICON m_hIcon;

// Generated message map functions
virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
afx_msg void OnPaint();
afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
CEdit tab1;
CEdit tab2;
CEdit tab3;
CEdit tab4;
CEdit tab5;
CEdit tab6;
CEdit tab7;
CEdit pos1;
CEdit pos2;
CEdit pos3;
CEdit pos4;
CEdit vel1;
CEdit vel2;
CEdit vel3;
CEdit vel4;
CEdit ferr1;
CEdit ferr2;
CEdit ferr3;
CEdit ferr4;
afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent);
};
```

The result I got from debugging.
NTDLL.DLL!77f8f397()
    NTDLL.DLL!77fa0346()

> mfc70d.dll!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance=, char * lpCmdLine=, int nCmdShow=)  Line 23    C++

- hInstance   CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found HINSTANCE__ *
  unused  CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  int
- hPrevInstance   CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  HINSTANCE__ *
  unused  CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  int
- lpCmdLine   CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  char *
      CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  char
  nCmdShow    CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  int

HINSTANCE__* should equal some value where as nothing has been found there. I am receiving 
77F8F397    CXX0013: Error: missing operator
Need help unpacking this Thanks.

Update :

I removed unnecessary CEdits. It doesn't produce any errors. The value for velocity and error is constantly zero, eventhough I know it should not display a zero.

Comment: Probably you're trying to set a value for a variable which it hasn't been created yet and that's why it won't let you to exceed your program's allowed memory area. Usually `0xC0...` addresses are referring to a null pointer.

Comment: How do I correct that? I think you are right. I added five new variables. I am not where they are at and where they are referencing.

Comment: Does this problem really occur only if you have 19 edit controls? I'm pretty sure it can be made shorter.

Comment: @user2809118 If I'd be honest, this is a wall of code and I can't say where the problem is located at. You should debug it yourself. Try to set breakpoints before each one of your suspected variables and see when the error is going to pop up, then you can decide which one is causing the malfunctioning.

Comment: Not sure still. I added what I am getting as result of debugging.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Without all the edit controls, how can they even work?

Comment: Hopefully the problem also occurs if you have only 18 edit controls. Maybe also 17. Repeat until you find the smallest program that still has the problem. (I suspect the About dialog is also not essential to the problem.)

Comment: @Raymond Chen The program doesn't produce any errors with 14 edit controls. The problem is that it doesn't produce the result I want to see in the display. And you are right, About Dialog is not essential. It is a different display.

Comment: You need to load ntdll symbols for the first two frames to be useful. You can use the symbol server to get them.

Comment: @ Raymond Chen I downloaded ntdll and other symbols. VS isn't able to incorporate it. I am still getting same errrors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use debugger!

- Run your application under debugger (F5 by default in Visual Studio).
- When exception will be thrown, press "Break". Application execution will be halted (debug breakpoint), and source code location of error will be shown.
- If error location is out of your code (probably somewhere in library code), look at "Call Stack" window and pick topmost function that you recognize. You will jump to location in your code that caused further problems.
- Look at "Autos" and "Locals" windows. Inspect values of variables, compare with values you expect. You will be able to find mistake quickly.

Happy debugging!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had updated the code with results I am getting from debugging. Can you help now? Thank you.

Comment: Hey Drop, I debug several times, Stack is not pointing to anything in my code. Please help.